# UITextView to Calculation Not Working

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

Consider the following code:

**Here is my price calculator controller header file.**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "PriceCalculator.h"

@interface PriceCalculatorController : UITextField {

    IBOutlet UITextField *mpgField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *milesField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *priceField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *ridersField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *splitField;

    PriceCalculator *calculator;
}


-(IBAction)calculator:(id)sender;

@end
```

**Here is its implementation file:**

```
#import "PriceCalculatorController.h"

@implementation PriceCalculatorController


- (IBAction)calculator:(id)sender {

    float split;

    calculator = [[PriceCalculator alloc]init];


    [calculator setMpg:[mpgField float]];
    [calculator setRiders: [ridersField float]];
    [calculator setMiles: [milesField float]];
    [calculator setPrice: [priceField float]];


    split = [calculator CalculateSplit];

    [splitField setFloatValue:split];
}
@end
```

It's giving me the error:

```
receiver type 'UITextField' for instance message does not
declare a method with selector 'float' [4]
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#import "PriceCalculatorController.h"

@implementation PriceCalculatorController


- (IBAction)calculator:(id)sender {

    float split;

    calculator = [[PriceCalculator alloc]init];


    [calculator setMpg:[mpgField.text floatValue]];
    [calculator setRiders: [ridersField.text floatValue]];
    [calculator setMiles: [milesField.text floatValue]];
    [calculator setPrice: [priceField.text floatValue]];


    split = [calculator CalculateSplit];

    [splitField setFloatValue:split];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2):

this may help you:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/87944-uitextview-calculation-not-working.html

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call the method `float` on each of your fields, and there IS no method `float`

Perhaps you meant something like `[mpgField.text floatValue];` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong code
change method like this

```
    [calculator setMpg:[mpgField floatValue]];
    [calculator setRiders: [ridersField floatValue]];
    [calculator setMiles: [milesField floatValue]];
    [calculator setPrice: [priceField floatValue]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to for a start define all of your IBOulets as @property(nonretain, atomic) ... and then synthesise them.

You will then need to call

> [[fieldname text] floatValue]

on the fields.

---

EDIT:

Here's the code you want:

```
[calculator setMpg:[[mpgField text] floatValue]];
[calculator setRiders: [[ridersField text] floatValue]];
[calculator setMiles: [[milesField text] floatValue]];
[calculator setPrice: [[priceField text] floatValue]];
```